# How to cover Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); in test class and assign id value to a child object

Tags: unit-test, apexpage

How can I cover these two lines in test class? I was able to cover first line but not the second. I need to create and assign the id to the child object.

```java
Id oppid = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
solist = [ select Order_Number__c from requested_item__c where quote_number__c=: oppid  and awarded__c=true order by Order_Number__c ASC];
```

Comment: Coverage is gained when a line of code is executed as part of running a test method. Unless you're getting an exception, there shouldn't be anything stopping your query from being executed. We'll need more context to be able to provide any real help here. This site thrives on details. Seeing the relevant parts of your test class and the class that your two-line snippet comes from will be important if you want an accurate answer. You can [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: You may also want to take a look through the questions under the [tag:canonical-qa] tag. There are several that go over unit testing, and you may find your underlying question already answered.

Comment: Are you looking to add the id value as a page parameter to test the code? In your test class, you can add this line setting the requested item id as a page parameter before calling the method containing your mentioned code:  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', requesteditemid);